# Replacing values randomly by taking values from another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I want to replace some of the values (say 3 values out of 10) of a variable from another variable. The selection must be random and must maintain the same id.

Here is one example data,

```
id <- c(seq(1:10))
a <- c(11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 109)
b <- c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, 1099)
data <- data.frame(id, a, b)
data

> data
   id   a    b
1   1  11  111
2   2  22  222
3   3  33  333
4   4  44  444
5   5  55  555
6   6  66  666
7   7  77  777
8   8  88  888
9   9  99  999
10 10 109 1099
```

Now let's say I want to replace 3 values in variable a with values from variable b under the same id. One example output could be,

```
> data
   id    a    b
1   1   11  111
2   2   22  222
3   3  333  333
4   4   44  444
5   5   55  555
6   6  666  666
7   7   77  777
8   8   88  888
9   9   99  999
10 10 1099 1099
```

Anyone can help me to do that? Tidy or data.table both solution is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one option where we create a `sample` of row index ('i1'), use to that assign the values of 'b' to 'a' in `base R`

```
i1 <- sample(seq_len(nrow(data)), 3, replace = FALSE)
data$a[i1] <- data$b[i1]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, create a condition with `row_number()` and use that in `case_when` (`ifelse` or `if_else` or `replace`) to change the values in 'a' to that of 'b'

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    mutate(a = case_when(row_number() %in% 
                   sample(id, 3, replace = FALSE) ~ b, TRUE ~ a))
```

---

Or with `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), specify the `i` with numeric index, and do the assignment (`:=`) in `j`

```
library(data.tbale)
setDT(data)[sample(id, 3, replace = FALSE), a := b][]
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am looking for a general solution. Also if I pointing out the position then it is not selected at random.

Comment: @small_lebowski  Yes, I showed 3 options.  Including one using the 'id' column

Comment: @small_lebowski  Updated with `sample`

Comment: `sample(nrow(data), 3)` is a more compact way to sample 3 of `nrow(data)` elements, though maybe philosophically objectionable.

Comment: Ok. I am not aware of the sample function. It works for first and third solution. 2nd option is giving me an error like this "Error: LHS of case 1 (`sample(id, 3, replace = FALSE)`) must be a logical vector, not an integer vector
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."

Comment: @small_lebowski  Sorry forgot the `row_number()` part fixed